# Return value as 'customvariablename'

Tags: php

I am attempting to crawl through a file and insert "../../" at the beginning of every image path.  Unfortunately though, the script is timing out, and since it only took a few seconds to run before this was added something tells me it is not doing what I think it should be.  This is how I'm doing it:

```
$filedata = substr_replace(substr($filedata,$imageBeginning,1),"../../",$imageBeginning);
```

I am crawling entire HTML files to accomplish this, so I need an efficient solution.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a good job for regular expressions :)

Comment: What would the best way be to accomplish finding the images with regular expressions be?  Right now I'm finding every file extension ending in '.jpg','.png','.bmp',or '.gif' and then tracing back to the first quote before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely untested, but something like this:

```
preg_replace('/(<img\s+.*?src=")(.*\\.(?:jpg|png|bmp|gif).*?>)/', '$1../../$2', $filedata);
```

Explanation: You are making 2 captures in the regular expression.  The first is everything from the start of the `img` tag to the start of the `src` attribute.  The second is the `src` attribute value and everything after it.  Then you just insert "../../" in the middle in the replacement.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: preg_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given.

Comment: Also, once that problem is sorted out, would this be proper?  preg_replace('/(<img\s+.*?src=")(.*\\.(?:jpg|png|bmp|gif).*?>)/', substr($filedata,0,$imageBeginning).'../../'. substr($filedata,($imageBeginning+1)));

Comment: Re your first comment, yep I just forgot to add the `$subject` parameter which is the text you are matching/replacing.  Have fixed above.

Comment: Re your second comment, no that is not correct, please read the description of `preg_replace` in the link I posted, in particular in relation to "references" as described under the `$replacement` parameter.  In short, you don't need to use `substr` because the regular expression is already doing that for you.

Comment: I somehow missed that.  I'm sorry for being a pain, I was frustrated/frazzled by the time I came to StackOverflow yesterday.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Actually, I've run into another problem that didn't occur to me...this only works for images in IMG tags and not those set as, say, backgrounds.  (not that I expect you to help me any further...I very much appreciate the effort you've given me thus far)